# Gridspec range error

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I'm having a simple error with matplotlib's gridspec that I just can't seem to figure out. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import matplitlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,3, width_ratios = [1,1], height_ratios = [2,1])
fig = plot.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax1 = plot.subplot(gs[:, :-1])
ax2 = plot.subplot(gs[:, -1])
```

The error I get with this code is

`IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4`

This doesn't make sense to me. What I think I'm saying with this code is that the first axis (ax1) should take up all of the rows, and live in the first two columns. The second axis (ax2) should take up all of the rows, and live in only the third column. Is this not what my code actually means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,3)` indicates that there is 1 row and 3 columns, but 
`width_ratios = [1,1]` implies there are 2 columns and `height_ratios = [2,1]` implies there are 2 rows. Unfortunately matplotlib does not catch the contradiction upon instantiation of `gs`, but the contradiction leads to the error later when

```
ax1 = plot.subplot(gs[:, :-1])
```

is called. To fix the error, you could specify 3 width ratios and a single height ratio:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,3, width_ratios=[1,2,3], height_ratios=[1])
```

for example.

Comment: Ah, so that's what's going on. Thank you very much.

Comment: please be aware that if you supply the ratios as a `map(...)`, it might run without error in Py2 but throw this error in Py3. this happened in my case